# Dynamically write to wallpaper layer Cinnamon DE / Linux

Tags: c, linux

I want to create a little dynamic/live wallpaper application for myself but i have no clue how i would actively write to whatever needs to be written to.
I have come across [this link](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xsetroot/tree/xsetroot.c) from a different post but im still new to lower level languages so im not sure how to use this or even if its really what i want